# Cleaning List using REGEX PYTHON

Tags: python, regex

I have the below list:

```
price_list = ['BK55.34', '5.67', '$4.63', '6:70', 'JB787']
```

My output should be:

```
price_list = [55.3, 5.67, 4.63, 670, 787]
```

How do I remove special characters such as '$' and ':' and letters such as 'BK' and 'JB' in Python using regex?

Comment: `[re.sub('[^\d.]', '', a) for a in price_list]`?

Comment: Have you tried using string methods? Something along the lines of `[float(''.join(s for s in i if s.isnumeric() or s =='.')) for i in price_list ]` should do

Answer (score 2):

You can try the regex `[^0-9.]` with the `sub` method of `re` that will remove any character that is not a number or a point and then cast the result if it has a point init then to a `float` else to an `int`.

```
price_list = [float(re.sub("[^0-9.]", "", i)) if "." in i else int(re.sub("[^0-9.]", "", i))  for i in price_list]
print(price_list)
```

OR without the if condition with `eval` that is more risky sinces you must be sure a the data in the list that it's not harmful

```
price_list = [eval(re.sub("[^0-9.]", "", i)) for i in price_list]
```

Output

```
[55.34, 5.67, 4.63, 670, 787]
```

Comment: You can shorten to: `price_list = [float(re.sub("[^0-9.]", "", i)) if "." in i else int(re.sub("[^0-9.]", "", i))  for i in price_list]`
`

Comment: Tnx for that will use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print(["".join(re.findall(r"(\d+)?:?(\d+)(\.\d+)?", s)[0]) for s in price_list])
```

Output:

```
['55.34', '5.67', '4.63', '670', '787']
```